# Spring Data ElasticSearch 4.0.0 - Using wildcards to search in multiple indexes of the same class

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

So i'm a novice in both ElasticSearch and Spring Data, and i've got an assignment to store the html contents of all outgoing e-mails.

```
@Document(indexName = "email")
@Mapping(mappingPath = "elastic/mappings/email.json")
public class EsOutboundEmail extends PartitionedDocument {
```

I've been told to index it by the month, i think it's for freezing old data later on, so i came up with something like this.

```
public String indexByMonth(AbstractDocument source) {
    final IndexCoordinates cos = elasticSearchMappingInitializer.getOrCreateDatedIndex(source.getClass());

    IndexQueryBuilder queryBuilder = new IndexQueryBuilder()
            .withId(source.getId())
            .withObject(source);

    return elasticsearchOperations.index(queryBuilder.build(), cos);
}
```

And the naming goes like this (ignore the "initializer" bean name, that's gonna change):

```
   public IndexCoordinates getOrCreateDatedIndex(Class<? extends AbstractDocument> clazz) {
       String indexName = getIndexName(clazz);
       indexName = String.format("%s-%s", indexName, now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM")));
       final IndexOperations indexOperations = elasticsearchOperations.indexOps(IndexCoordinates.of(indexName));
       if (!indexOperations.exists()) {
           indexOperations.create();
           indexOperations.createMapping(clazz);
       }
       return IndexCoordinates.of(indexName);
   }

   public String getIndexName(Class<? extends AbstractDocument> clazz) {
       if (!clazz.isAnnotationPresent(Document.class)) {
           throw new IllegalStateException("Elasticsearch domain must have @Document annotation!");
       }

       Document annotation = clazz.getDeclaredAnnotation(Document.class);
       return annotation.indexName();
   }
```

So the result would be `email-2020-06`.

Now, searching in this feels a little off:

```
    public <T extends AbstractDocument> T searchOneDated(Query query, Class<T> clazz) {
        String indexName = elasticSearchMappingInitializer.getIndexName(clazz);
        indexName = format("%s-*", indexName);

        return ofNullable(elasticsearchOperations.searchOne(query, clazz, IndexCoordinates.of(indexName)))
                .map(SearchHit::getContent)
                .orElse(null);
    }
```

I can't shake the feeling that there's a way to do this in a much simpler way, but like i said, i'm a novice, and the reference documentation for 4.0.0 did not help with this case, so i'd appreciate any input from someone who knows more about this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a SpEL expression in the `@Document` annotation, for your case this would be for example:

```
@Document(indexName="email-#{T(java.time.LocalDate).now().format(T(java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter).ofPattern(\"yyyy-MM\"))}")
public class EsOutboundEmail extends PartitionedDocument {
  // ...
}
```

For saving an entity:

```
ESOutboundEmail email = ...;
elasticsearchOperations.save(email);
```

and for searching:

```
elasticsearchOperations.searchOne(query, clazz)
```

You still would need to make sure that the index is created if it does not exist (note that I added the call to `putMapping(Document)`, you missed that):

```
   final IndexOperations indexOperations = elasticsearchOperations.indexOps(EsOutboundEmail.class);
   if (!indexOperations.exists()) {
       indexOperations.create();
       Document mapping = indexOperations.createMapping(clazz);
       indexOperations.putMapping(mapping);
   }
```

**Edit 2020-06-16:**

I missed the wildcard in the search:

```
elasticsearchOperations.searchOne(query, clazz, IndexCoordinates.of("email-*"))
```

Comment: And if i use SpEL in the index name, will #search use wildcards to check all indexes related to that @Document?

Comment: I updated my answer, you just use the `email-*` directly as parameter

Comment: that wildcard in `IndexCoordinates` is freaking awesome. We have indexes per environment and this is a life saver. thank you so much.